# How to use ionic with others web component simultaneously Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, nebular

I'm trying to create an apps which use nebular and ionic in the same project.

I have 2 parent routes, `pages` for nebular layout and `ionic` for ionic layout.

Inside `ionic` component I wrap everything using this code

```
<ion-app>
  <ion-router-outlet></ion-router-outlet>
</ion-app>
```

it is a standard layout for ionic, and its working just fine. but then, inside `ionic`s child page, every time I use `ion-content`, everything inside `ion-content` is not rendered. But when I inspect`ion-content` and its content actually exist.

Here's if I don't use `ion-content`

[image]

Here's if I use it:

[image]

As you can see, `ion-content` actually exists. Any idea why?

EDIT

the problem was actually i forgot the routing thanks to [alex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11210003/alex), but it still have an issue with the routing.

if i click one of the messages using `routerLink` to `/ionic/message/USERID` i cant see the inside of that message.
[image]
it's blank but the message is exsist, then when i reload it's rendered but `app-home` doesn't exsist.
[image]

why is that?

Comment: From your source it looks like your ion-content isn't actually a child of ion-app which is probably why content isn't displaying in it.

Comment: well yeah since u said that it's now make sense. now i just realized that the supposed-to-be-children component is actually isn't a children of `ionic` page so i change the `ionic-routing-module`  now it works !

Comment: Glad to hear it!

Comment: but i'm still have an issue with this, i updated my question

Comment: can u help me ?

Comment: I'm not sure I can see what your problem is from the screenshot, sorry.